# ffmpeg: What does the format 'null' imply?

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, mpeg4

I am trying to understand exactly what does the 'null' format imply. I did read the documentation from:

- https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#null

But I fail to understand the following scenario. Consider:

```
$ ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i input.mkv -ss 0 -t 1 -an -sn -c:v mpeg4 -f mp4 /dev/null
[mpeg4 @ 0x562dc220aa00] Failed to parse extradata
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 01:07:47.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1433 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile), yuv420p, 688x512 [SAR 1:1 DAR 43:32], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 01:07:47.920000000
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 80 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 01:07:47.880000000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp4, to '/dev/null':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 688x512 [SAR 1:1 DAR 43:32], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 01:07:47.920000000
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 mpeg4
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=   25 fps=0.0 q=1.6 Lsize=      16kB time=00:00:00.96 bitrate= 140.1kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=32.3x    
video:15kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 6.221970%
```

While with null format:

```
$ ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i input.mkv -ss 0 -t 1 -an -sn -c:v mpeg4 -f null /dev/null
[mpeg4 @ 0x5645807d5a00] Failed to parse extradata
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 01:07:47.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1433 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile), yuv420p, 688x512 [SAR 1:1 DAR 43:32], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 01:07:47.920000000
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 80 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 01:07:47.880000000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, null, to '/dev/null':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 688x512 [SAR 1:1 DAR 43:32], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 01:07:47.920000000
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 mpeg4
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
[mpeg4 @ 0x564580804380] Invalid pts (2) <= last (3)
Video encoding failed
Conversion failed!
```

How should I interpret the above error ? Repeated below:

```
[mpeg4 @ 0x564580804380] Invalid pts (2) <= last (3)
Video encoding failed
Conversion failed!
```

---

Update, using `-enc_time_base -1` gives:

```
$ ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i input.mkv -ss 0 -t 1 -an -sn -c:v mpeg4 -enc_time_base -1  -f null /dev/null 
[mpeg4 @ 0x561134551ac0] Failed to parse extradata
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 01:07:47.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1433 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile), yuv420p, 688x512 [SAR 1:1 DAR 43:32], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 01:07:47.920000000
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 80 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 01:07:47.880000000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, null, to '/dev/null':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 688x512 [SAR 1:1 DAR 43:32], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 01:07:47.920000000
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 mpeg4
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
[mpeg4 @ 0x561134582100] Invalid pts (80) <= last (120)
Video encoding failed
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null muxer accepts the packets from the encoder and discards them. There's no processing of the packets or any I/O operations performed.

What `-f mp4 /dev/null` does is pass the packets to the MP4 muxer and then direct the I/O destination of the MP4 muxer to `/dev/null`. So, as far as the MP4 muxer is concerned, it's writing out data. The OS takes care of discarding received data.

What happens with the null muxer is that it sets the time base of the video stream to the inverse of the frame rate. For variable frame rate streams, that can lead to clashing or non-monotonic timestamps which the MPEG-4 encoder does not like. Add `-enc_time_base -1`

Comment: It appears that I need both `-enc_time_base -1` *and* `-vsync 2`. [ref](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2018-May/039926.html)

Comment: Only if the frame rate detected for the source is very high >= 1000.